# How to insert labels on to x-axis bar graph using matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am obviously doing something wrong since I get a warning using python3 matplotlib -
UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

Also, the plot labels are not drawn correctly, it seems like it is overlapping or something broken.
Basically, I want each point to represent labels like -

Total_Ticks
Time_in_secs
Iterations/sec
Iterations

However, it is not showing that. What is wrong and what am I missing here?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from matplotlib import ticker

data = [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0909675345548056, 1.0909675345548056, 2.499866074843752, 2.727272727272727], [1.255062680810029, 1.255062680810029, 4.346034298168655, 5.454545454545454]
print(data)
X = np.arange(4)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
labels = ['Total_Ticks', 'Time_in_secs', 'Iterations/sec', 'Iterations']
ax.bar(X + 0.00, data[0], color = 'b', width = 0.25)
ax.bar(X + 0.25, data[1], color = 'g', width = 0.25)
ax.bar(X + 0.50, data[2], color = 'r', width = 0.25)
# save the figure
ax.legend(labels=['intel', 'amd','apple'])
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
plt.savefig('plot.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 0):

set width of labels:

> ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0.25,3.25,4))

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from matplotlib import ticker

data = [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0909675345548056, 1.0909675345548056, 2.499866074843752, 2.727272727272727], [1.255062680810029, 1.255062680810029, 4.346034298168655, 5.454545454545454]]
print(data)
X = np.arange(4)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
labels = ['Total_Ticks', 'Time_in_secs', 'Iterations/sec', 'Iterations']
ax.bar(X + 0.00, data[0], color = 'b', width = 0.25)
ax.bar(X + 0.25, data[1], color = 'g', width = 0.25)
ax.bar(X + 0.50, data[2], color = 'r', width = 0.25)
# save the figure
ax.legend(labels=['intel', 'amd','apple'])
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0.25,3.25,4))
plt.savefig('plot.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```